# How do you use Yes/No to input your answer C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, statements

I have my program here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string input;
cout << "say yes or no" << endl;
cin >> input;
if(input == Yes)
{
    cout << "test" << endl;
}
else if(input == No)
{
    cout << "test123" << endl;
}
system("pause");
}
```

It says that Yes and No are undefined?
Please help I am new to c++

Comment: Yes and No are not defined, they should be in quote as they are string.
A better approach is to use set of answer as user may answer in uper letter or lower letter
or best take whatever input user want and the convert it to all lower and then compare (you have function for toLower in string library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use doubleQuotes for string "Yes" "No"

Comment: @user2460300 I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int FNum = 1, UserInput;   
    char choice;
    
    do{
        
    std::cout << "Factorial Calculator" << std::endl;
    
    cout << "Enter an integer (1-10): ";
    
    std::cin >> UserInput;

    for(int i = 1; i<=UserInput; i++){
         FNum = FNum *i;
      
    }
    
    cout << FNum << std::endl;

    
    cout << "Do you want to quit?\n[Y]es\t[N]o\n";
    cin >> choice;
      
    }while ((choice == 'y') || (choice == 'Y') ); system("play");
  
    return 0;
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

First, Yes and No without double quote are read as variable by the compilator, and you didn't declare any Yes or No variable.

Second, I don't think you can compare String like that in C++ : you have to use compare ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/ ) so the prog will be :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string input;
  cout << "say yes or no" << endl;
  cin >> input;
  if(input.compare("Yes"))
  {
    cout << "test" << endl;
  }
  else if(input.compare("No"))
  {
    cout << "test123" << endl;
  }
  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Do some case-folding too. As it is, it asks for "yes or no", but does not accept "yes" or "no" as an answer.

Comment: @user2458606 string has these operator as overloaded operator

Comment: _" I don't think you can compare String like that in C++"_. That's wrong. Note that `compare` will return 0 when the strings are equal. So `input.compare("Yes")` will evaluate to `false` when the input is `"Yes"` and to `true` for _any other input_. Simply use `==`.